Creating separate groups in a dataframe when column values repeat
I have a dataframe with numbers formatted as follows:
df = pd.DataFrame({"ColumnA": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], "ColumnB": [1,3,5,6,4,7,5,4,1,2], "ColumnC": [0,1,1,2,0,2,1,1,0,1]})

Which gives:



ColumnA
ColumnB
ColumnC




1
1
0


2
3
1


3
5
1


4
6
2


5
4
0


6
7
2


7
5
1


8
4
1


9
1
0


10
2
1



I want to combine based on groups in ColumnC, averaging ColumnA, and summing ColumnB to give something like this:



ColumnA
ColumnB
ColumnC




1
1
0


2.5
8
1


4
6
2


5
4
0


6
7
2


7.5
9
1


9
1
0


10
2
1



I've tried:
dfGrouped = df.groupby(df["ColumnC"]).aggregate({"ColumnC":"first","ColumnA":"mean","ColumnB":"sum"})

Which gives:



ColumnC
ColumnA
ColumnB




0
5
6


1
6
19


2
5
13



I understand why it does not work, but I need help in working out exactly how to get it give the desired output. The order of the columns does not matter too much because I will do more manipulations after, but getting it to group 'locally' rather than 'globally' is where I am currently stuck.
Thanks in advance.

Use dfGrouped = df.groupby(df["ColumnC"].ne(df["ColumnC"].shift()).cumsum()).aggregate({"ColumnC":"first","ColumnA":"mean","ColumnB":"sum"})
